# Adding array to Pandas dataframe as row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add an array to an existing `pandas` dataframe as row. Below is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['tom', 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
print(df)

Y = [10, 100]

df.loc[0] = list(Y)
print(df)
```

Basically I want to add `Y` to `df` as row without disturbing existing rows. I also want to add column names of final `df` as `'Y1' and 'Y2'`

Clearly with above code existing information of `df` appears to be replaced with `Y`.

Could you please help me with right code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `loc` adding the value by exiting `row` and additional `columns`

```
df.loc[0,['Y1','Y2']] =Y
df
  Name  Age    Y1     Y2
0  tom   10  10.0  100.0
```